# LaTeX symbol unknown

Tags: symbols

What the LaTeX code is for this fancy 0?

[image: Fancy 0?]

I have been looking for the LaTeX code for this zero-like symbol and I can't seem to find it anywhere.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Do you have a PDF version of this document? What fonts does it contain? Anything would be better than a photo taken of a screen (which is what it looks like you're showing us.) But symbol/font requests are usually closed as duplicates of [How do I find out what fonts are used in a document/picture?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/45919) or [How to look up a symbol or identify a letter from a math alphabet or other character?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/14).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to look up a symbol or identify a letter from a math alphabet or other character?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-letter-from-a-math-alphabet-or-other-chara)

Comment: This looks like the letter 'o' in a different font, like QT Heidelberg Type or something of the sort. I'm voting to close this as this is a typographical question more related to font IMO than to a TeX question

Answer (score 16):

This is the zero in the Euler fraktur font by Hermann Zapf.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

$-\lambda w=\mathfrak{0}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh boy... I've spent at least ten minutes looking for different small o in various fraktur fonts and I've never thought of 0...

Comment: @campa haha I did the same thing!

Comment: @campa To be honest, I too tried for “o”, but then “hey, it's math!”.

Comment: In case you don't use LaTeX for anything related to math, you recognize Zapf's Euler math after reading once his [alphabeth-stories](https://www.rit.edu/press/alphabet-stories).

Comment: Greatest! :-) :-)